# Bootstrap Inline form with 2 inputs with less padding between them

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form made with twitter-bootstrap that has 2 input fields inline nested in 2 columns(see the code below)

What's the best way to remove padding between 2 inputs to make it look like the following image:

[image]

**--question**

Should I add a wrapper and id's to each of the inputs and then add custom styling like `padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;`

or there's a better way to accomplish this?

**form html**

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="" class="sky-form ">
  <fieldset class="no-padding">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-11 col-lg-offset-0">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="input">Left text field</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-0">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="input pull-right ">RightF #</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

**output1** `col-lg-11 col-lg-1`

[image]

**output2** `col-lg-10 col-lg-2`

[image]

Comment: I am assuming you are using Bootstrap, if yes the padding is on the columns, so just remove the padding on the columns not the input.

Comment: @acardoso , thanks. In this case I have to add custom media queries, since when the cols collapse there shouldn't be any padding on left and right.

Comment: If you are looking only for `lg` do something like this: `@media (min-width: 1200) { ... }`, but really it looks like you should be using input addons http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

Comment: @acardoso `@media (min-width: 1200)` this is actually what I already tried :D and it works

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using Bootstrap. The framework is written in a way that every column adds padding. Your output is right. All you have to do is remove padding from the columns. Showing below:

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="" class="sky-form ">
  <fieldset class="no-padding">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-11 col-lg-offset-0" style="padding-right:0">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="input">Left text field</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-0" style="padding-left:0">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="input pull-right ">RightF #</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason of spaces between two inline elements is because of the font-size. Read [this](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) article to read how can you remove this.

One way to remove this space is to give *negative margins*.